# LINQ/Projection - An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The code below is giving the following error:

***"An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"***

```
var x = db.Data.Select(x => new { name = TitleHT[x.TitleId], x.TitleId }).GroupBy(x => x.name);
```

TitleHT is a `Dictionary<int, string>` so that I can look up the string representation of the TitleId.  As such I'm trying to assign the name to this string literal in the query .  TitleId is of type int? not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: So... Do any parts of that involve dynamic? What is db.Data, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged your question with "linq-to-sql" so I assume that the db is a L2S DataContext.  In that case the LINQ Provider attempts to convert TitleHT[x.TitleId] to a SQL statement but is unable to.  Something like this should work:

```
var x = db.Data
    .Select(x => x.TitleId)
    .ToList() // Subsequent projection using LINQ-to-Objects
    .Select(x => new { name = TitleHT[x], TitleId = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.name);
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `ToList()` though, consider using `AsEnumerable()` instead.

Comment: @JeffMercado that's true for certain scenarios.  It really depends if you want to maintain deferred execution or not.

Comment: @PhilKlein: Thanks for the reply. x.TitleId isn't getting resolved from the second Select.   The only options that are showing up per intellisense are "HasValue", "Value", Equals, etc,.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the answer. Hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: @PhilKlein: Doh, yep makes sense.  I actually had to update the TitleHT[x] to TitleHT[x.Value] and worked like a charm.  :)  Thx Phil!